# Performance considerations when using @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, performance, warnings, query-performance

I hope you're well.

This post is in regards of the performance considerations while using a @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") when retrieving database information. I came with a question to leads in my company and it seems to b a gray area. The example is as follows.

Scenario 1:

```
public List<BusinessObject> retrieveInformation(Long id){
    List<? extends Object> info = persistenceService.get("namedQuery", params, values);
    //... cast the contents one by one to List<BusinessObject> and return
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
public List<BusinessObject> retrieveInformation(Long id){
    List<?> info = persistenceService.get("namedQuery", params, values);
    //... cast the contents one by one to List<BusinessObject> and return
}
```

Scenario 3:

```
public List<BusinessObject> retrieveInformation(Long id){
    List<BusinessObject> info = (List<BusinessObject>)persistenceService.get("namedQuery", params, values);
    //... return the List<BusinessObject>
}
```

Scenario 4:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public List<BusinessObject> retrieveInformation(Long id){
    List<BusinessObject> info = persistenceService.get("namedQuery", params, values);
    //... return the List<BusinessObject>
}
```

Of course, there are a lot more ways of doing this, but my concern is a way of doing this process with the best performance.
So, we need to take into account that while retrieving the information, we may have a mistake in the query and there is going to be an exception; also, if the there is no such mistake, we do already know the type of objects that are going to be retrieved.

So, thinking on this from the perspective of a big business project, with all their components in place, say hibernate layer, DAO and DTO, could you please help me determine:

1. One option with the best performance considerations.
2. If the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation has performnce considerations.
3. If getting rid of @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is a good practice in this scope.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Because of type erasure, none of this has any effect at runtime.

Comment: Annotations are at compile time.

Comment: Just one more question, a warning in this case would be considered a code smell? Would it be better to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `@SuppressWarnings` annotations have no performance implications.  They don't materially alter the bytecodes that are generated.

Unnecessary type casts in the source code should be omitted by the byte code compiler, but the compiler will include whatever type-casts are necessary to ensure runtime type safety, irrespective of the suppression of warnings<sup>1</sup>.

Furthermore if (hypothetically) the compiler does insert some type-cast bytecodes that are not strictly necessary, they *should* be optimized away by the JIT compiler.

---

However, it is better to write your code so that you don't need to use `@SuppressWarnings` annotations.  The problem is that the annotations can hide logic errors in your code; i.e the warnings can be real.  If not detected by thorough unit *and* integration testing, these can lead to unexpected runtime errors.

---

<sup>1 - If the compiler didn't do this, then the bytecodes would fail verification when loaded by the JVM.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

@SuppressWarnings only affects the compiler, and only to stop the compiler from showing warnings.

When assigning to generic lists, all that is happening is that the compiler gets an opportunity to verify compatibility of the types. At run time, the generics information is erased.

Scenario 3 is your best bet, assuming that your are getting a List from your call, from a code quality perspective. All four scenarios will produce the same output.